# d3 diagonal between two points

Tags: d3.js, diagonal

I have points that I would like to create diagonal lines with. I don't want to use a tree layout, I just want two points and a diagonal line.

The following code is throwing an error: 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined "

---updated WORKING code ------

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
//The data for our line
var lineData = [
    {
        "source": {
            "x": 100,
            "y": 300
        },
        "target": {
            "x": 200,
            "y": 400
        },
        "number":5
    },
    {
        "source": {
            "x": 150,
            "y": 350
        },
        "target": {
            "x": 250,
            "y": 450
        },
        "number":10
    },    
];

var lineFunction = d3.svg.diagonal()
   .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x] })

var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                .attr("width", 1000)
                                .attr("height", 1000);

svgContainer.selectAll("lines")
    .data(lineData)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", lineFunction)
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.number+"px"})
    .attr("fill", "none");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the entire `lineData` array into the `lineFunction` but it should just be an individual datum.  Since you bound `lineData` to the selection, you could do `.attr("d", lineFunction)`.

There are some problems with your `diagonal` as well.  The `source` and `target` accessors both need to return objects, where in your case they are returning scalar values.

Then, the result objects returned from `source` and `target` will be subsequently fed into `projection` where each should be further converted into a 2 element array describing a point.  If your `source` and `target` return an object with `x` and `y` defined (`{x:, y:}`) you don't need `projection` at all because the default will look for these properties.

Comment: When I change it to .datum nothing happens.

Comment: I've updated the code, I now get the error message "Error: Problem parsing d="M,C, , ," "

Comment: I read the docs more closely and I was confused about the purpose of "projection".  I've updated the answer to hopefully clarify.

Comment: thanks for your help, i did modify your suggestions slightly, i still use .data and kept the .projection but you helped me see the object portion of d3.svg.diagonal. I've updated my working code.